use group_by function with if/then/else condition
I have a dateframe like this one with variables corresponding to death on inclusion and variables corresponding to death on follow-up visits:



Id
death_inclusion
date_death_inc
follow-up
death_followup
date_death_followup




1
yes
2004-08-15





2
no

1
no



2
no

2
no



2
no

3
yes
2011-10-16


3
no

1
no



3
no

2
no



4
no

1
yes
2013-05-03



I would like to obtain a dataframe like the one below to have the vital status of the patient whether he died at inclusion or at one of the follow-up visits. I was thinking of using functions such as “group_by” and if/ then/else



Id
death
date_death




1
yes
2004-08-15


2
yes
2011-10-16


3
no



4
yes
2013-05-03



Here's a reproducible code
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "2", "2","2","3","3","4"),
                 death_inclusion = c("Yes", "No", "No","No","No","No","No"),
                 date_death_inc = c("2004-08-15", "", "","","","",""),
                 follow_up = c("", "1", "2","3","1","2","1"),
                 death_followup = c("", "No", "No","Yes","No","No","Yes"),
                 date_death_followup = c("", "", "","2011-10-16","","","2013-05-03")
)


df$date_death_inc<-as.Date(df$date_death_inc,format="%Y-%m-%d")
df$date_death_followup<-as.Date(df$date_death_followup,format="%Y-%m-%d") 

Thank you for your help

You can try the following code:
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, 
       date_death=coalesce(date_death_inc, date_death_followup), .by=ID) |>
  summarise(death=ifelse(any(!is.na(date_death_inc) | 
                               !is.na(date_death_followup)), "yes", "no"), 
            date_death=if_else(death=="yes", first(na.omit(date_death)), NA), .by=ID)


  ID death date_death
1  1   yes 2004-08-15
2  2   yes 2011-10-16
3  3    no       <NA>
4  4   yes 2013-05-03


df <- structure(list(ID = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4"), death_inclusion = c("Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"), date_death_inc = structure(c(12645, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), follow_up = c("", "1", 
"2", "3", "1", "2", "1"), death_followup = c("", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), date_death_followup = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 15263, NA, NA, 15828), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")


If the data is well organised
x = subset(df, death_inclusion=="Yes"|df$death_followup=="Yes", 
           c(ID, date_death_inc, date_death_followup))
rbind(cbind(x[1L], date_death = na.omit(Reduce(c, x[-1L]))), 
      cbind(ID = setdiff(unique(df$ID), x$ID), date_death = NA)) |> sort_by(~ID)

   ID date_death
1   1 2004-08-15
4   2 2011-10-16
11  3       <NA>
7   4 2013-05-03

I suspect the information death="yes"|"no" is contained in the date_death column. Another base option would be aggregate + merge + ifelse. Or reshaping the data frame to long format.
